# $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2(\tan x-\sin x)-x^3}{x^5}=$?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Original question: $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2(\tan x-\sin x)-x^3}{x^5}$$

What is wrong in my solution as answer is $\frac14$ not $\frac12$:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2({\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\sin x)}-x^3}{x^5}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2(\sin x-\sin x\cos x)-x^3\cos x}{x^5\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin x(1-\cos x)-x^3\cos x}{x^5\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(2\sin x)(2\sin^2 (\frac{x}{2}))-x^3\cos x}{x^5\cos x}$$
Dividing by $x^3$ and distributing $x$ and $x^2$ between $\sin x$ and $\sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})$ respectively,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4(\frac{\sin x}{x})(\frac{\sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})}{x^2})-\cos x}{x^2\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\frac{\sin x}{x})(\frac{\sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})}{\frac{x^2}{4}})-\cos x}{x^2\cos x}$$
Now I assumed $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $(\frac{\sin (\frac{x}{2})}{\frac{x}{2}})^2$ to be 1 as $x\to 0$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{x^2\cos x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{4(\frac{x^2}{4})\cos x}$$
Again $(\frac{\sin (\frac{x}{2})}{\frac{x}{2}})^2$ to be 1 as $x\to 0$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2\cos x}$$
And now as $x\to0$ $\cos x$ will be $1$. So that's how I got $\frac12$. I am learning limits. So, correcting me will improve my misconceptions.

Comment: To me it appears that the problem is that you've replaced part of the function we're taking the limit of with its limit midway through the calculation, we can't exactly do that

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: This was my first time. Next time i will try not use pictures of handwritten solution. But what is the error in this solution? If you can understand from the image.

Comment: You should have a look at [this mathjax tutorial written especially for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/72031) and then you won't need to include images of handwritten math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Stephen pointed out in the comment, the problem is taking the limit in the third line of your computation. Using $S(x)=\sin(x)/x$, by adding $-1+1$ in the nominator, the correct expression is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{S(x)S(x/2)-\cos(x)}{x^2\cos(x)}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{S(x)S(x/2)+\frac{1}{2}S(x/2)x^2-1}{x^2\cos(x)}\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{S(x)S(x/2)-1}{x^2\cos(x)}+\frac{1}{2},$$
and the first contribution to the limit is exactly the missing $-1/4$.
If it is an option, I would recommend to apply L'Hôpital's rule, which is usually also used to obtain $S(0)=1$. Then, with $\tan'(x)=1+\tan(x)^2$, $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$, $\cos'(x)=\sin(x)$, $(x^r)'=rx^{r-1}$ for $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ and the chain rule we get
$$\frac{2(\tan(x)-\sin(x))-x^3}{x^5}\rightarrow
\frac{2+2\tan(x)^2-2\cos(x)-3x^2}{5x^4}\rightarrow
\frac{4\tan(x)+4\tan(x)^3+2\sin(x)-6x}{20x^3}\rightarrow
\frac{4+16\tan(x)^2+12\tan(x)^4+2\cos(x)-6}{60x^2}\rightarrow
\frac{32\tan(x)+80\tan(x)^3+48\tan(x)^5-2\sin(x)}{120x}\rightarrow
\frac{32+272\tan(x)^2+480\tan(x)^4+240\tan(x)^6-2\cos(x)}{120}\rightarrow
\frac{1}{4}.$$
As a more general bugfixing strategy, I recommend to plot the function in each step of your computations, for example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), from say $x=-0.05$ to $x=0.05$ (if this option is available). This helps to identify the faulty step. If you further keep track of the error terms (as illustrated above by adding $+1-1$), you can not only determine the limit, but also the asymptotical behavior as the limit is approached.

Comment: No, I used taylor's trigonometric expansion and L'Hôpital's Rule and I got 1/4 but with these steps i also wanted to know why i can't just do that simply in the third line of solution. Does it mean i cannot distribute limit specifically to some term?

Comment: Yes, as pointed out in the first equation in my answer, the term that you neglected is the limit of $[S(x)S(x/2)-1]/x^2\cos(x)\rightarrow-1/4$. The reason is that you replaced both $S(x)$ and $S(x/2)$ by $1$, thus you obtained $0$, while the limit is in fact $-1/4$ (since $0$ is also a second order root in the nominator).

Comment: Can you prove how [S(x)S(x/2)-1]/x^2cosx is -1/4?

Comment: I think the easiest way to prove this is to use the direct proof with L'Hôpital's Rule above, and then obtain $-1/4=1/4-1/2$ as the difference .